# Grails- how to open a modal in the gsp

Tags: grails, modal-dialog

If a condition is exist I have to open a modal window which is in a template called "thanksContactModal", and have id "thank-contact-us".

I try to use the following code:

```
<g:if test="${messageSent}"><div><g:render template="thanksContactModal"> </g:render></div></g:if>
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should open it by JavaScript, if you use bootstrap modal, so you should impliment next code:

```
<g:if test="${messageSent}">
   $('#thank-contact-us').modal('show')
</g:if>
```

if thank-contact-us is id of your modal window. Good luck

Comment: @Koloritnij- You can't write javaScript code inside <g:if></g:if>

Comment: sure? <script><g:if test="${messageSent}">
   $('#thank-contact-us').modal('show')
</g:if> </script> try this one. Of course it work with <r:script> and <asset:script>

Comment: You can't do it in a gsp file

Comment: It work fine because I often use it. And looping by <g:each> work in script too. Maybe problem in your code?

Comment: you may find if you have a gsp page that does not load in the sitemesh i.e. main layout not defined then the <g:if tags may not work within javascripts etc (a page that is a template too) can have these sort of issues.. try defining it in a <g:javascript> container